# iterate array and add new field to each nested array

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a JSON array from an AJAX call that looks like the following:

```
[{field1: "Something", field2: "Other"},{field1: "Something", field2: "Other"},{field1: "Something", field2: "Other"}]
```

I want to use this data on DataTables, but I would like to add a text input to each row in the table based on field Title (Group). Therefore, I would like to add this column to each array, something like:

```
[{field1: "Something", field2: "Other", Group: "Text Input"},{field1: "Something", field2: "Other", Group: "Text Input"},{field1: "Something", field2: "Other", Group: "Text Input"}]
```

So that DataTables will add a text input on each new row. How is this achievable using jQuery or javascript?

I have tried by iterating trough the array:

```
var i, j, arrayItem;
for (i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    arrayItem = array[i];
    arrayItem.push({Group: "Text Input"});
}
```

But this shows error, `"Push" is not a function`. As you can see, the JSON array has no explicit index for each nested array, and each array is not unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entries in your array aren't arrays, they're *objects*. (Arrays are also objects, but those entries aren't arrays.) To add a property to an object, the simple way is just to assign to it:

```
arrayItem.Group = "text input";
```

You can use a `for` loop for that as you have done, which is absolutely fine, or as of ES5 and above (or with a polyfill for obsolete environments) you could use `forEach`:

```
array.forEach(function(entry) {
    entry.Group = "text input";
});
```

This has the advantage that you don't need those `i` and `arrayItem` variables.

In ES2015+ you could use a `for-of` loop:

```
for (const entry of array) {
    entry.Group = "text input";
}
```

...which has the same advantage (`entry` is only defined inside the loop).

Comment: I see, how can I differentiate as to when I am refering to nested object instead of nested array?. I have been struggling with this for a while haha.

Comment: `[...]` denotes an array. `{...}` denotes a non-array object.

Comment: I shall leave this question here, as it will probably help others in the future :D

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I could easily understand my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot push because it is an object. Just assign to the object.

```js
var fields = [{
  field1: "Something",
  field2: "Other"
}, {
  field1: "Something",
  field2: "Other"
}, {
  field1: "Something",
  field2: "Other"
}]

fields.forEach(x =>
  x.Group = "Text Input"
)
console.log(fields)
```

Answer (score 1):

`{field1: "Something", field2: "Other"}` is not an array, it's an object. Arrays are surrounded with `[]`, objects are in `{}` and the elements are `key: value`.

You don't use `push()` to add to an object, you simply assign the property.

```
array.forEach(e => e.Group = "text Input");
```

or

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].Group = "text Input";
}
```